# How can I run a bash script from an absolute path versus a relative path

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a file in my root directory called `bash_scripts` and within it I have a file called `create_py_dir.sh`.  At present the only command in the shell script is `pwd`, which I am using just to ensure it is working correctly.  The directory structure is shown below;

```
desktop
|
myname(i.e. root directory)
    |
    bash_scripts
        |
        create_py_dir.sh
```

If I `cd` to the same directory as the scripts and run a `pwd` command it tells me that the file is in the directory `/Users/myname/bash_scripts`.  So lets say that I go back to the root directory and up one directory to the desktop via `cd ../desktop` and from there I run the script via relative path with `./../bash_scripts/create_py_dir.sh`, the scripts works just fine.  However, if I try to execute it via an absolute path with `./Users/myname/bash_scripts/create_py_dir.sh` I get the following error, `./Users/myname/bash_scripts/create_py_dir.sh: No such file or directory`.  I think I have a fundamental understanding problem with how to run shell scripts from absolute paths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`./Users/myname/bash_scripts/create_py_dir.sh` is not an absolute path.

A `.` is a reference to the current folder.

This would be an example of an absolute path:
`/Users/myname/bash_scripts/create_py_dir.sh`

(assuming the directory `Users` exists in the top level of the file system)

Comment: Such a simple nuance, I am embarrassed I did not notice that.  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! If this solved your problem, please accept the answer.

Comment: To put a finer point on it:  An absolute path starts with `/`; anything else will be a relative path.

Comment: @panki, sort I was at work all day and this is the first chance I have had to accept it.